# Angular: linking data to dynamic table using *ngFor

Tags: json, angular, dynamic, ngfor

I am creating a dynamic table. The problem with my json structure below is that the Students object does not contain Subjects array within the object, but rather Students[] and Subjects[] are defined through Links[], where there is link defined for student a subject.

The output of the table should look like this:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions how to create *ngFor in **???** area that links each student to its subjects?

The json structure looks like this:

```
export class StudentsAndSubjects {
 info: SchoolInformation;
}

export class SchoolInformation {
 students: Students[];
 subjects: Subjects[];
 links: Links[];
}

export class Students {
 id: string;   //example: student_1
 name: string;
 surname: string;
};
export class Subjects{
 id: string;   //example: subject_1
 name: string;
};
export class Links{
 studentId: string; //example: student_1
 subjectId: string; //example: subject_1
};
```

The table structure:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-student-and-subjects',
 template: `
   <table>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of rowHeaders">
        <td *ngFor="let item of data.info.students.name">
           <span *ngIf="row !== 'Subjects'">{{ item[row] }}</span>
        </td>
        <table *ngIf="row === 'Subjects'">
            <tr **???**>
               <td>{{ subject}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </tr>
   </table>
`;
})
export class StudentsAndSubjects {
 @Input() data: StudentSubjectData;
 readonly rowHeaders = ['Student','Subjects']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need to restructure your table a bit. Since the table of subjects is associated to a particular student, it should probably live inside the `td` that contains that student's data:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rowHeaders">
    <td *ngFor="let student of data.info.students"> <--- each td contains data for a student
      <span *ngIf="row !== 'Subjects'">{{ student.name }}</span>

      <table *ngIf="row === 'Subjects'"> <--- move this table inside the td
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let subject of getSubjectsForStudent(student)"> <-- the *ngFor you were missing
            {{ subject.name }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also note that I changed your `*ngFor="let item of data.info.students.name"` so it iterates over `data.info.students` rather than `data.info.students.name` since you need the student instance data (and `data.info.students.name` isn't a collection).

And to display the student name, I replaced `{{ item[row] }}` with `{{ student.name }}`.

Then, to display the subjects for that student, you would need to create a method that accepts the student object (or just its `id`) and then parses the data and returns the student's associated subjects.

That method is what you would need in the missing `*ngFor` that you're asking about.

(Alternatively, of course, you could transform the data ahead of time into a mapping object that maps the students to their subjects.)

So the missing `*ngFor` that you're asking about would look something like this:

```html
<td *ngFor="let subject of getSubjectsForStudent(student)">
```

Note that it's on the `td`, not the `tr` like in your markup. That's because each subject has its own cell, not its own row—all subjects are in the same row.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w7i24g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) showing this approach.

Comment: Hi @MikeJ. Can you please find what mistake am I making? I updated the JSON links with 1 additional field for result and I need to display this value under specific student and subject. However, with the function implemented, I´m receiving error - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zvtvyp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Victoria you're just missing a `return` on line 54 of `app.component.ts` in the `subjectIds.map` callback function: `return links.find((link) => link.subjectId === subjectId);`.
Because that callback function uses curly braces (i.e., it has a _block body_, not a _concise body_), it does not do an implicit return—you need to use an explicit `return` statement. [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body).